# Can I serve archive files right away in httpd or ftp?

Tags: ftp, httpd, webdav, archive

I want to serve an archive file as a virtual directory to users.

example)

```
server:
 a.tar
 L___ hello.txt
 L___ world.txt

client:
 http://server.local/a.tar/hello.txt
 http://server.local/a.tar/world.txt
```

Is there a plugin for any server (httpd/ftp/webdav...) that makes this possible?

Linux's archivemount is not considered.

Thanks you.

Comment: FTP servers used to do this way back in the 80s and 90s, but it was resource intensive on the server and fell out of favor. Most everyone eventually disabled it. I've never heard of a web server doing it.

Comment: It is not heavy service.
I want to just see a file in the tar archived backup.

Comment: That requires reading the entire file each time you do it. How big is it? How many times will it be read?

Comment: The size is 160gb and the number of files is about 100,000.
I found out that archive files do not have indexes.
So now I'm looking for something that can serve squashfs instead of tar.